# Invalid Cast Exception in HttpFileCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, httppostedfile, httpfilecollection

I have an extension method below, but when I run this, the foreach gives me `InvalidCastException` and it says *

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.String' to type
>   'System.Web.HttpPostedFile'.

**Code :**

```
public static List<Attachment> GetFiles(this HttpFileCollection collection) {
            if (collection.Count > 0) {
                List<Attachment> items = new List<Attachment>();
                foreach (HttpPostedFile _file in collection) {
                    if (_file.ContentLength > 0)
                        items.Add(new Attachment()
                        {
                            ContentType = _file.ContentType,
                            Name = _file.FileName.LastIndexOf('\\') > 0 ? _file.FileName.Substring(_file.FileName.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) : _file.FileName,
                            Size = _file.ContentLength / 1024,
                            FileContent = new Binary(new BinaryReader(_file.InputStream).ReadBytes((int)_file.InputStream.Length))
                        });

                    else
                        continue;
                }
                return items;
            } else
                return null;
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

**MSDN Says :**

> Clients encode files and transmit them
>   in the content body using multipart
>   MIME format with an HTTP Content-Type
>   header of multipart/form-data. ASP.NET
>   extracts the encoded file(s) from the
>   content body into individual members
>   of an HttpFileCollection. Methods and
>   properties of the HttpPostedFile class
>   provide access to the contents and
>   properties of each file.

Comment: in which line its throwing this error in this code given

Comment: @solairaja, when it first hits `foreach (HttpPostedFile _file in collection)` line of code, it gives the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the code sample on this page, it shows how you should enumerate the collection, you are in fact getting a string when you try to enumerate as you are.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpfilecollection.aspx

Comment: Yes.  The string you are getting back is the name of the input element corresponding to the file.  If you want, you can just do a for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++) { HttpPostedFile file = collection[i]; /* remainder of code here */ }.

Answer (score 3):

The [`HttpFileCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpfilecollection.aspx) collection enumerator returns keys. You need to use the key in each iteration of the loop to look up the associated [`HttpPostedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx) object. So your loop needs to look like this:

```
foreach (string name in collection) {
    HttpPostedFile _file = collection[name];
    // ...rest of your loop code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I've found a solution but it looks so stupid but it works.

I've simply changed the `foreach` with this one :

```
foreach (string fileString in collection.AllKeys) {
                    HttpPostedFile _file = collection[fileString];
                    if (_file.ContentLength > 0)

                        items.Add(new Attachment()
                        {
                            ContentType = _file.ContentType,
                            Name = _file.FileName.LastIndexOf('\\') > 0 ? _file.FileName.Substring(_file.FileName.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) : _file.FileName,
                            Size = _file.ContentLength / 1024,
                            FileContent = new Binary(new BinaryReader(_file.InputStream).ReadBytes((int)_file.InputStream.Length))
                        });

                    else
                        continue;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
  for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
  {
     HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
     if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
    {
     string _fileSavePath = _DocPhysicalPath  + "_" + hpf.FileName;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Put the HtpCollection Request file that will be having an collection of array's  into httpposted file. It will help if there are more than one file uploader on a page to find out which one is uploaded on a page.